# xcalib only works upon restarting computer

Tags: gnome, 16.04, xcalib

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1 LTS on a Dell XPS 13 laptop. After installing xcalib, running "xcalib -i -a" won't invert colors initially; instead, it only works when I set my laptop to sleep then turn it on again. The reverse is also true, making color inversion a real hassle. There also aren't any error messages being displayed when I run xcalib; it just enters the next command prompt as if everything worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!